# Minecraft mod 1.12.2 glass bug

Tags: java, graphics, minecraft

I'm doing a simple Minecraft mod, but I have problem with custom glass block:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqlbJB4d16OZu0TtNAG68on1C3EN?e=Fl9Ecv

Block under,and behind glass block are visible. How can I fix it?

if there is space between next block is visible:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqlbJB4d16OZu0X-Wjd-hx3_wGEF?e=LQoAao

```
public class HardGlass extends BlockBase
{

    public HardGlass(String name, Material material) 
    {
        super(name, material);
        
        setSoundType(SoundType.GLASS);
        setHardness(600.0F);
        setResistance(100.0F);
        setHarvestLevel("pixaxe",3);
        setLightOpacity(1);
        
    }
    
    
    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    public BlockRenderLayer getBlockLayer()
    {
        return BlockRenderLayer.CUTOUT;
    }

    public boolean isFullCube(IBlockState state)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this solved the problem, and I can still put doors on it ;)

```
    @Override
public boolean isOpaqueCube(IBlockState state) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return false for isFullCube so MC will render the blocks around it.

Comment: still the same, also i want to keep that becouse i want to put doors/levers on this block